# Javascript : Creating object with dynamic property

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function which returns an object that will contain a property based on a parameter of the function.

Something like

```
var my_object_creator = function(prop, value) {
    return { prop: value }
}
```

But the value of the property should not be "prop", but to evaluate the value of `prop`, and this is the property name.

I know I can do it like this

```
 var my_object_creator = function(prop, value) {
    var t =  {};
    t[prop] = value;
    return t;
}
```

But I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In ES2015:

```
return { [prop]: value };
```

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate.